# how to secure $_GET

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to secure my `$_GET` inputs everything are working the problem is `$_GET['action']` can't pass `preg_match()` and always resulta in:

> "action is not valid"

I don't know why it's happening, the action can have only two values like or hate which both are in lowercase but still can't pass it.

```
if(isset($_GET['username']) && isset($_GET['action']))
{
    $username = $_GET['username'];  
    $action = $_GET['action'];

    $user_filter_a = mysqli_real_escape_string($username);
    $user_filter_b = mysqli_real_escape_string($user_filter_a);
    $user_filter_c = strip_tags($user_filter_b);

    $action_filter_a = mysqli_real_escape_string($action);
    $action_filter_b = mysqli_real_escape_string($action_filter_a);
    $action_filter_c = strip_tags($action_filter_b);
    $action_filter_c_lower = strip_tags($action_filter_b);

    if(preg_match('%^[a-z0-9\.]{4,69}$%',$user_filter_c))
    {
        if(preg_match('%^[a-z]$%',$action_filter_c_lower))
        {
           if($action_filter_c_lower=='like')
           {
               echo 'you have liked this post';
           }elseif(action_filter_c_lower=='hate')
           {
               echo 'you have hated this post';
           }
        }else
        {
            echo 'action is not valid';
        }
    }else
    {
        echo 'username is not valid';
    }
```

Comment: `^[a-z]$` matches strings which are exactly 1 character long.

Comment: There is no reason to call `mysqli_real_escape_string` twice.

Comment: Also `$action_filter_c_lower = strip_tags($action_filter_b);` should probably be `$action_filter_c_lower =strtolower($action_filter_c);`

Comment: For your information, `isset()` can be fed multiple variables with the same behavior  as your if statement.  Dots don't need escaping inside of a character class.

Comment: These variable names are really confusing and hard to read, it makes it easy to get your wires crossed.  Don't be afraid to reuse the same variable.  It can make the code a lot easier to follow.  You could make that stuff a function, and get rid of the duplication.  You'll probably find some of the issues vanish once you clean it up.

Answer (score 2):

When you need to validate that a string is completely comprised of letters, you can use `ctype_alpha()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/EGI04))

```
$string = 'asdgadsfg';
if (ctype_alpha($string)) {
    echo "all alphabetical";
} else {
    echo "not entirely alphabetical";
}
```

Output:

```
all alphabetical
```

---

If you need to check if a submitted value is `like`, `hate`, or [something else]; create a "whitelist" array to look up the value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/pjhOr))

```
$string = 'like';
$whitelist = ['like', 'hate'];
if (in_array($string, $whitelist)) {
    echo "valid: $string";
} else {
    echo "invalid: $string";
}
```

Output:

```
valid: like
```

---

Additional tips:

```
if(isset($_GET['username']) && isset($_GET['action']))
```

can be written more simply as:

```
if (isset($_GET['username'], $_GET['action'])) {
```

You shouldn't be performing escaping until just before applying the data to the query, this way you don't accidentally mangle your data or confuse yourself.  Honest, I always use prepared statements to build a query with user-submitted data, so I'll recommend that you research that topic.

In your regular expression, you don't need to escape a dot inside of a character class so the character class can look like this: `[a-z0-9.]`  If you also wish to allow capital letters, you can add `i` after the end pattern delimiter (`%`) so that it looks like `%^[a-z0-9.]{4,69}$%i`  or `%^[a-z\d.]{4,69}$%i`.

`_lower` is a strange thing to append to your variable name, because you aren't calling any functions that force the string to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

The total number of actions is limited. It is more secure to not use the user input at all. Instead, use a switch statement with a default action:

```
$userAction = strtolower($_GET['action']);
switch($userAction) {
    case "like":
        $action = "like";
        break;
    case "hate":
        $action = "hate";
        break;
    default:
        $action = "default-action";
}
```

Or, you can have the list of valid actions in an array:

```
$validAction = ["like","hate","other"];
$action = "";
if (in_array($_GET["action"],$validAction)){
    $action = $_GET["action"];
}
```

Here you have the guarantee that the action is valid.

Comment: Would you really use a verbose switch block for this task?  If the needle is in the "haystack", use the needle, if not use the default-action.